Closed form for infinite product involving a polynomial of degree 4
Suppose $a$, $b$  two reals different from $0$, and consider the following infinite product:
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigg[ 1+ 2\ i \cdot \frac{n^2 + a\ n+b}{n^2+(n^2+a\ n+b)^2}   \Bigg]
\end{align}
where $i$ is the imaginary unit.
Question: is it possible to find a closed form for this product? Or at least with $a$, $b$ having some restrictions?
Infinite products involving terms like $1+\frac{1}{P(n)}$ where $P(n)$ is a polynomial of degree 2 can be sometimes solved with a closed form but I have not seen anything with polynomial of higher degree.

From this post, one can find a reference to
"On gamma quotients and infinite products" by M.Chamberland and A.Straub where we have the following:
\begin{equation}
\prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(k+\alpha_1)...(k+\alpha_n)} {(k+\beta_1)...(k+\beta_n)} = \frac{\Gamma(\beta_1)...\Gamma(\beta_n)}
{\Gamma(\alpha_1)...\Gamma(\alpha_n)}
\end{equation}
if $\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n = \beta_1+...+\beta_n$.
Note that in the original question, the numerator $N$ and denominator $D$ of the product term are
\begin{align}
N &= n^2 + (n^2+a\ n+b)^2 + 2\ i\ (n^2+a\ n+b) \\
D &= n^2 + (n^2+a\ n+b)^2
\end{align}
and so $N$ and $D$ have the same coefficient in $n^3$, i.e. the sum of the roots is the same for $N$ and $D$, which is exactly the requirement for applying the formula.
Since N and D are polynomials of degree 4, there exists exact formulas for computing their roots and then get a closed expression in terms of the gamma function for the infinite product.
